# wkhtmtopdf on IBM powerbox ppc64le

Tags: qt, server, wkhtmltopdf, rhel7

I need to install the package "wkhtmltopdf" on RHEL 7 on IBM power Ecosystem ppc64le.
I tried installing a normal package but it give error

```
"-bash: ./wkhtmltopdf: cannot execute binary file"
```

I found build script on github for the IBM powerbox on the link:
[wkhtmltopdf_rhel_7.4.sh](https://github.com/ppc64le/build-scripts/blob/master/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf_rhel_7.4.sh)

It tries to git clone -reccursively, which isnt allowed on our sever due to security policies.
I understand **wkhtml needs qtbase** so have downloaded both the individual packages (wkhtml & qtbase5.11) reading & navigating through the script on provided link.

Now, I'm stuck about setting up QT.
**What next?**

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf-0.12.1 exists for ppc64le as an EPEL package (https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/ppc64le/Packages/w/)